# MIPS 32 - Subroutine that can calculate factorials (using sll and add)

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, factorial, mips32

So my professor has been confusing the heck out of me since the beginning of the semester, and he just gave us this assignment to calculate factorials in MIPS using only a subroutine with "sll" and "add." He already made us implement his code of calculating factorials using "mult" but he wanted us to try writing this subroutine on our own.

He gave us this flow chart for how we should go about it, and I sort of get the idea of how to implement it, but his way of explaining things always leaves me even more confused than before.

[Flowchart Provided Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKDoI.png)

My current subroutine is implemented as this. I know that there's a lot of unnecessary implementations, but I'm just so lost, I don't want to change anything right now.

```
#Part 2 subroutine
#t6 = 2nd array
#t3 = least significant bit temp (for checking)
#t4 = sum of t4 + s1(previous result)
#s6 = product of t4 * 2

loop_partB:
addi $t6, $t6, 4 #Part B Pointer Update
andi $t3, $s1, 1 #finds the lsb in y
lsb_check:
bnez $t3, adder
beqz $t3, shifter
shifter:
add $t4, $t4, $s1
sll $s6, $t4, 1 # Multiply by 2
sw $s6, ($t6) #storing product into $t6 array
jr $ra
adder:
b shifter
```

With this current subroutine, I was able to draw out the process on paper, and I know that after 6, the products start to become incorrect.

The main loop that he provided for us before for calculating factorials using "mult" is implemented like this:

```
#Variable and array initializations

la $t6, factsB
lbu $t7, size #size for printing later

la $t0, facts
lbu $t5, size
subu $t1, $t5, 1
li $s0, 1
li $s1, 1
sw $s1, ($t0)
sw $s1, ($t6)

# === LOOP STARTS HERE

loop_main: #Calculates Factorials
addiu $t0, $t0, 4
addiu $s0, $s0, 1
jal loop_partB #Call for the subroutine I'm trying to implement
multu $s0, $s1
mflo $s1
sw $s1, ($t0)
subi $t1, $t1, 1
bgtz $t1, loop_main
```

The size of the array is set to 12, and the first element is set to 1

$s0 and $s1 are the numbers being multiplied, $s1 holds the product and gets stored into an array.
The process repeats, as it should for a factorial.

Here is the output for both arrays for factorial of 5. The numbers under [Part B] are the results of using my subroutine.

```
Factorials 
1 2 6 24 120 
Factorials [Part B]
1 2 6 18 66
```

I'm trying not to ask for the exact answer, I'm just so confused by the way my professor explained it. I'm having a hard time understanding how exactly I'm supposed to replicate a factorial function using only sll and add.

Comment: Why does your code need an `sw`? Should it just take two values, X and Y, and return X*Y? Also, why is there no code after `adder:` except for a jump?

Comment: Expressed in C it would look something like this: `int X = 5, Y = 24, product = 0;
    for (int N = 0; N < 32 && X != 0 && Y != 0; N++) {
        if (Y & (1 << N)) {
            product += X;
        }
        X<<= 1;
    }`

Comment: @Michael It's supposed to store it into the second array being printed, and like I said, there is a lot of unnecessary pieces still in there because I didn't want to change anything for this post. Thank you, but I unfortunately do not know C, only Java.

Comment: Fortunately for you C and Java are very similar syntactically, so someone who knows Java should be able to understand the code I posted just fine. The code is actually valid Java as well, aside from the implicit `int` to `boolean` conversion in the `if` statement.